# stream Video from url in kudan videotexture

Tags: android, kudan

I use kudan sdk for augmented reality for android development.
in video texture we have 2 method for loading video. (loadFromAsset and loadFromPath)
but I need streaming video from url.
Please help me. how can I do it.

Comment: Well, since the only available methods seem to require the video file to be on the device, then I expect there isn't a way to livestream an online camera feed.